# Can I use always emplace to replace insert for single element insertion?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering if it is OK to always use `emplace` to replace `insert` when inserting a single element into a STL container, like set, unordered_set?

From the signature, `emplace` is simpler and do not involve overloads. Is there any issue with stop using `insert` and use `emplace` all the time?

Note: there are SO questions asking about the difference between `emplace` and `insert`/`push_back` etc. (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893000/when-to-use-emplace-and-when-to-use-push-insert), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659292/what-is-difference-between-insert-and-emplace-for-vector-in-c)) I understand the difference, and it seems to me that `emplace` is better in every way. I just want to confirm if it's OK to deprecate `insert`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080290/are-there-any-cases-where-it-is-incorrect-to-replace-push-back-with-emplace-back) that can be adapted to `emplace` and `insert`, showing when the behaviour may differ.

These examples may seem a bit artificial, so I'll give one that will hopefully appear less so:

```
#include <set>

template <typename T>
T id(T x) { return x; }

int main() {
    std::set<int(*)(int)> s;
    s.insert(id);       // OK
    s.emplace(id);      // error
    s.emplace(id<int>); // OK
}
```

`insert` can deduce the template parameter of `id` because it knows what type it wants. For `emplace` you get an error unless you explicitly specify.

Comment: What a surprise. Thanks. But `emplace` should be OK if no templates involved?

Comment: @TingL You can also have non-template overloaded functions. For these the manual resolution is even worse (you need `static_cast`).

Answer (score 4):

Always?  No, certainly not.

Consider the following example, which uses `std::vector` for simplicity (assume `uptr` is a smart pointer acting generally like `std::unique_ptr`):

```
std::vector<uptr<T>> vec;
vec.insert(vec.begin(), new T());
```

It is exception-safe.  A temporary `uptr` is created to pass to `insert`, which is moved into the vector.  If reallocation of the vector fails, the allocated `T` is owned by a smart pointer which correctly deletes it.

Compare to:

```
std::vector<std::uptr<T>> vec;
vec.emplace(vec.begin(), new T());
```

`emplace` is not allowed to create a temporary object.  The `uptr` will be created once, in-place in the vector.  If reallocation fails, there is no location for in-place creation, and no smart pointer will ever be initialized.  The `T` will be leaked.

Of course, the best alternative is:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> vec;
vec.insert(vec.begin(), make_unique<T>());
```

which uses a standard smart pointer and makes the smart pointer creation explicit.

Comment: @T.C.: Which you won't notice if you've decided to always use `emplace` instead of `insert`.  `emplace` will happily call the explicit constructor.

Comment: Right, but the first example isn't exception-safe - it simply won't compile.

Comment: Hmm, I would claim that any smart pointer type with ownership semantics that can be implicitly constructed from a raw pointer is too dangerous to be used.

Comment: @T.C.: Then all the various things that effortlessly call explicit constructors, like `emplace`, should also be too dangerous?  Yes, an `explicit` constructor helps prevent this problem in other scenarios, and emplace happily bypasses that protection.

Comment: -1. considering  taking care of exceptions thrown when realloc fails is waste of time.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It need not be the memory allocation that failed, `T` might have a copy/move constructor that can throw. In any case, that's a silly reason to downvote an answer that describes an important distinction. Examples on SO are more often contrived than not, and the expectation is you'll look beyond that to the concept that it's trying to teach. Also, can you be certain that there's not a single program out there that doesn't handle `std::bad_alloc`?

Comment: @Praetorian ofc they are, for example I can imagine programs doing trying to get max buffer they can, then if it fails try 80% of that, if that fails 80% of that... but in general exception safety when it comes to bad_alloc just makes code less readable and offers no benefits IMAO. If new fails just die....

Comment: daamit, scott meyers agrees with you... :D  Ill remove the vote if A gets edited, for now SO wont let me...